# ClassNotFoundException for GridLayoutManager when minifyEnabled

Tags: java, android, proguard, logcat, minify

I´am trying to minify my application with proguard but when i set minifyenabled to true i get this error on start of the applicaton.

Any idea what could be wrong since it works fine without it?

I´am only using these libraries if that makes any difference:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${23.1.1}"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${23.1.1}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${23.1.1}"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${23.1.1}"
```

Crash log:

```
8754-8754/se.jsoft.xxxE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: se.jsoft.xxx, PID: 8754
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.jsoft.xxx/se.jsoft.xxx.activity.CategorySelectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                  at se.jsoft.xxx.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.u.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.k.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.e(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ac.o(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.x.onStart(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                  at se.jsoft.xxx.b.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.u.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.k.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.e(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ac.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.x.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                  at se.jsoft.xxx.b.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.u.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.k.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.e(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ac.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.x.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binary XML file line #3: Unable to find LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                  at se.jsoft.xxx.b.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.u.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.k.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.e(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ac.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.x.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/se.jsoft.xxx-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/se.jsoft.xxx-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                  at se.jsoft.xxx.b.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.u.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.k.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ag.e(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.ac.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.support.v4.b.x.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 30 more
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: are you using a custom proguard rules file? or just the android default? there's not much info here without code, proguard config, or the XML file.... maybe you need to `keep` that `GridLayoutManager` that's throwing a `ClassNotFoundException`, as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-2-minifying-code-554560d2ed40#.vrpq5w10e)

Comment: It works with the info provided in the link! Thx!